# "Should not already be working" on window.open in simple React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'll post here a heavily simplified version of the webapp I'm working with.

Basically I get an `Uncaught Error: Should not already be working.` on the `window.open(...)` line of the following code:

```
const sleep = milliseconds => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, milliseconds));
const spawnWind = async () => {
    let newwin = window.open("about:blank", "TEST", "popup,height=260,width=370");
    await sleep(2000);
    newwin.close();
}

useEffect(() => {
    spawnWind()
    .then(() => console.log("After spawnWind"));        
}, []);
```

This is triggered only on one specific condition: if I access the component which has this code from inside the react app (like from a navbar) and the component **has never been mounted before** then the error is triggered. In all these other scenarios I have no errors whatsoever:

- refresh the page after the error is triggered (so, for example, refreshing directly the page when I'm on `mysite.com/mycomponent`;
- accessing directly by url (so directly typing `mysite.com/mycomponent`; this makes perfect sense since it's basically the same as refreshing)
- accessing the component a second time after having triggered the error on the first access (for example: I access `mysite.com`, use navbat to navigate to the page with component, the error is triggered. Navigate away with navbar and go back **without refreshing** then no error is triggered).

I have no idea of what the cause can be. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** according to the (as the time of writing) [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17355) on React's GitHub (mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76945127/12904316)), this is a *Firefox-specific* issue (locally tested with Chromium, everything works).

Comment: Can you check if my answer works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code to:

```
const sleep = milliseconds => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, milliseconds));

const spawnWind = async () => {
  let newwin = window.open("about:blank", "TEST", "popup,height=260,width=370");
  await sleep(2000);
  newwin.close();

  console.log("After spawnWind")
}

useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(spawnWind, 0)
}, []);
```

---

This is an [open bug in react](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17355) about this issue.

The issue is because of the blocking call `window.open` within the `useState` hook, which messes with React's synchronisation of the state.

The only solution so far is to wrap the blocking calls inside a `setTimeout()`: using a delay of 0, as stated in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout), executes the code passed to `setTimeout` in the next event cycle, allowing pending rendering to finish (check the issue mentioned above).